# Binding issue on silverlight datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

I have a datagrid on which I want to bind the foreground colour of a column like so :

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Bid Qty" Binding="{Binding Path=BidPrice.QuantityString}" Foreground="{Binding BidPrice.TextColour}" />
```

But I am getting this error in the form init :

```
Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn.Foreground' threw an exception. [Line: 95 Position: 106]

Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.
```

I tried setting the type of TextColour to be SolidColorBrush but that did not help.

EDIT:

Bid price is a type of product price :

```
    public class ProductPrice
    {
        public SolidColorBrush TextColour { get; set; }
}
```

And set like so :

```
private void SetColours(ProductPrice price, string firmPriceColour = "Black", string impliedPriceColour = "Black")
{
    if (price != null)
    {
        if (price.IsImplied.GetValueOrDefault(false))
            price.TextColour = ColourHelper.StringToColorBrush(impliedPriceColour);
        else
            price.TextColour = ColourHelper.StringToColorBrush(firmPriceColour);
    }
}
```

Note it could possible be null.

Comment: Post your code for `BidPrice`.

Comment: What is `BidPrice`? How is the datacontext being set?

Answer (score 0):

Create a SolidColorBrush and bind BidPrice.TextColour to it's Color property. Then bind DataGridTextColumn.Foreground to that brush.